# Find the limit as $x$ goes to infinity of the $x$-th root of a polynomial in $x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{p(x)}$$

where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of finite degree.

I've tried to use the continuity of $\exp$ and $\log$ :

$$\exp(\log(\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{p(x)}))=\exp(\lim_{x\to \infty}\log( \sqrt[x]{p(x)}))=\exp(\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{\log(p(x))}{x})$$

I would like to conclude that the limit is zero so it turns out to be $e^0=1$
How can I do it rigorously? I've seen that log is asymptotically slower than x. I would get it if in the denominator there was $p(x)$ with a change of variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{p(n)}=1$ for polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160868/prove-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtnpn-1-for-polynomial)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1716776/42969

Comment: Yes it does, i didn't specify but is is >0 for all x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both rigourously and in a short way: use *asymptotic equivalents*:

- if $p(x)=ax^n+ \text{terms of lower degree}$, then 
  $$p(x)\sim_\infty ax^n, \quad\text{so}\quad \frac{\log p(x)}{x}\sim_\infty\frac{\log(ax^n)}x=\frac{\log a +n\log x}x.$$